# @-sign in output / list

Tags: r, list, output

I'm writing a function with a list as output.
It should be very user friendly but I need to add additional information to the output. I don't want to add another element that can be accessed by a `$` sign. I've seen the `@` sign as an alternative sometimes. Unfortunately I don't have an example for that and googling was not successful. Can you tell me how I can achieve this? Or do you have another solution for my problem with 'hidden' information in an output?

Comment: You will need to provide a sample input and a sample output.

Comment: `@` is `s4`(equivalent of OOP in R?), `$` is mainly `s3`

Comment: You could add “hidden” information in the attributes. To access them you could build a helper function. The attributes are not a great way of storing information, but it would be an option.

Comment: @TimTeaFan: Great, that's a very good idea! Thank you!

Comment: @TimTeaFan: If you want, you can post this as an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: I already posted this approach as an answer ;) See below.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have something like this in mind:

```r
# list object
ll <- list(data = data.frame(a = 5:10, b = 15:20))

# add class `special_list`
class(ll) <- c("special_list", class(ll))

# add info in an attribute called `hidden`
# hidden here means not accessable by `$` operator
attr(ll, "hidden") <- list(a = c("a", "b"),
                           b = c("c", "d"))

# infex helper function to subset the data in hidden
`%@%` <- function(x, n) {
  .var <- deparse(substitute(n))
  if (!"special_list" %in% class(x)) 
    stop("this function only works on objects of class 'special_list'")
    else attr(x, "hidden")[[.var]]
} 

# get element `a` in attribute hidden 
ll %@% a
#> [1] "a" "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This part is even enough for my case: `attr(ll, "hidden") <- list(a = c("a", "b"),
                           b = c("c", "d"))`. Did not think of attributes, great!